# How can I put a POST inside another POST in PHP

Tags: php, post

I am trying to take the contents of a form and i want to display them using PHP. The way the form is structured is the following:
There is a list of checkboxes, which when they are clicked, a JavaScript function will create another `<input>` tag. The JS then sets the name of the new input to `<input name="value of checkbox">`.

What I need to do is get my PHP to take the value of the `<input>` I created.
Here is my HTML of the checkboxes.

> `<input name="product[]" value="value of Check 1" id="id-check-1" type="checkbox" onclick="id-check-1"/>`
> `<input name="product[]" value="value of Check 2" id="id-check-2" type="checkbox" onclick="id-check-2"/>`
> `<input name="product[]" value="value of Check 3" id="id-check-3" type="checkbox" onclick="id-check-3"/>`

Here is my HTML of the inputs created by the JS.

> `<input name="value of Check 1" type="text"/>`
> `<input name="value of Check 2" type="text"/>`
> `<input name="value of Check 3" type="text"/>`

PHP:

> `$aProduct = $_POST['product];`
>     `$product1 = $aProduct[0];`
>     `$product2 = $aProduct[1];`
>     `$product3 = $aProduct[2];`
>     `$input1 = $_POST[$product1];`
>     `$input2 = $_POST[$product3];`
>     `$input3 = $_POST[$product3];`

I tried using this PHP to obtain the value inputted to the crated inputs. This shouldwork, since the name of the inputs = the value of the checkboxes, so in short, this is what I've done:`$_POST[$_POST['product']]`

Unfortunately, it doesnt work and the variables $input1, $input2 & $input3 dont return any value. So I'd like to know: A) Can i put a _POST within a _POST? and B) What can I do to make my code work?

Comment: Do $product1, etc. contain a value? I'm thinking you don't need to do what you think you do.

Comment: What do you put in the text box? Also post the js code.

Comment: Yes. the value of $product1 is "value of Check 1" taken from the first HTML code

Comment: If the input values are in an array, it would be $_POST['product'][0] etc?

Comment: In the text box I put the quantity of products. i.e. a number

Comment: what do you mean @DerekS ? What do i need to do then

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

First of alll the $_POST Variable is one Super Global in PHP i dont think it makes any sense to use $_POST[$_POST...

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

Also i dont think you have to create extra inputs just use $_POST['product'] (array of values which are selected)

try var_dump($_POST['product']) to see whats stored in it

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly otherwise guide me in the right direction.

First: You have given the name product[]. Then it should be $_POST['product[]'] which I don't know if that is possible.

Second: If you are writing the value of the checkbox to an input field than why not just check the checkboxes by name. For example:

```
<input name="check1" value="checkbox 1 value" type="text"/>
<input name="check2" value="checkbox 2 value" type="text"/>
<input name="check3" value="checkbox 3 value" type="text"/>
```

then in php do:

$check1 = isset($_POST['check1']) ? $_POST['check1'] : "";

This way if the checkbutton is checked you get the value of check1 and otherwise it's empty.

Comment: I could do that, but there is a really long list of checkboxes, and i didnt want to have to write so many lines of PHP...

Comment: But what do you want to do with the values? Because a simple foreach could save all the post values

Answer (score 0):

Potentially, you are having issues because you can't have whitespace in the name attribute.

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name